# Understanding Delphi Variable Declarations/Initializations

Tags: delphi, variable-assignment, variable-initialization

As it pertains to Delphi...

When a variable is declare of a certain type, is it initialized to an OBJECT of that type? Or must the variable be assigned an expression which returns an object of that type?

I'm coming from a strong Java background. What I mean to ask is this...
In Java, say you declare an instance variable of a user defined type named Orange. Which would look like this:

```
private Orange _fruit;
```

The variable _fruit still holds a reference to null until actually assigned an instance of the Orange class, like this:

```
_fruit = new Orange();
```

In Delphi if I declare a variable of type TForm, like this:

```
var
  Form : TForm;
```

Is Form initlized to a TForm object? Or is it still nil?

I'm asking because I'm getting an error when trying to compile a small bit of code which is showen below:

Here is the Main unit:

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils,
  System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Second;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ShowForm2: TButton;
    procedure ShowForm2Click(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  SecondForm : TSecondForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ShowForm2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
SecondForm.ShowModal;
end;
end.
```

and here is the Second unit:

```
unit Second;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TSecondForm = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
  end;

var
  SecondForm: TSecondForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

The error I'm getting when I try to compile is exactly: "Access violation at address 005B17F9 in module 'Multiple.exe'. Read of address 00000000." I was thinking that it's because I don't somehow initialize the variable SecondForm in unit Main? However, I tried to place 'SecondForm.Create' in the ShowForm2Click procedure and I get the same error. Am I get this error because SecondForm is unassigned? Does it need to be initialized? Or is it?

Note:
I'm three days new to Delphi. Please be considerate of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

also note that `unit Second` and `unit Main` both declare a global variable

```
SecondForm : TSecondForm;
```

In the case of the main unit your main unit will be hiding the `SecondForm` variable declared in `unit Second` (even though it lists it in the `uses` clause).  In the case of a Delphi VCL Forms application, if the `SecondForm` is an auto-create form then the `SecondForm` declared in `unit Second` will not be `nil` and will in fact already have an instance of `TSecondForm` created and assigned to it, but this will be inaccessible by `unit Main` because it declares a global of the same name (which, like all reference types, will be `nil` until you do something with it).

In short, it's probably best not to declare a global `SecondForm : TSecondForm` in `unit Main` - call it something else or else use the global declared in `unit Second`.  If `SecondForm` is an auto-create form (default behaviour) then the above code would work if you simply did not re-declare `SecondForm` in `unit Main` - if not you would still have to instantiate `SecondForm`.

VCL Forms are automatically auto-create forms unless you otherwise specify.  Check menu:

```
 Project > Options > Forms
```

to see or change which forms will automatically have an instance assigned to their IDE-generated globals.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much!But if I may ask one question just to make sure I'm understanding? (I'm new to the RAD environment too.) So when I auto create a new VCL form...it doesn't have to be instantiated? But any record or class or form etc. that isn't auto-created does have to be instantiated?

Comment: @diosteama if you look at your project code (right-click on your executable in the project manager, and view source), you will see that Delphi has generated some code to instantiate the auto-created form.

Comment: @diosteama - yes, essentially.  When you add a new form to your project the IDE always adds a global instance variable for the form and puts it into the auto-create list.  This implies that it also creates code to instantiate that global (as Blorgbeard has noted).  If you don't want the default global instantiated then simply remove the form from the auto-create list.

Comment: @diosteama - also, to be complete, you don't have to instantiate records (only classes); records allocate all the space they need when declared.  If they are records of reference types then their members need to have instances created, but otherwise records are just packages of primitives or pointers and do not need any creation.

Comment: But note that statically allocated methods exist even if the object doesn't exist. So you are able to call those methods of an object that hasn't been instantiated, only declared.

Answer (score 5):

`SecondForm.Create` is  the wrong syntax.  Constructors are special in Delphi.  You can think of them more or less like class methods.  The way you invoke them is like this:

```
variable := ClassType.Create(arguments);
```

While it is possible to invoke a constructor like an instance method (`variable.Create`) this is for one specific use case and should not be done in general code.  The reason to call a constructor on an object and not a type is *if you're already inside a constructor for that object.*  (ie. if you have more than one constructor on the object and one of them calls another one, or to initialize the ancestor class's members by calling a constructor on the parent class with `inherited Create(arguments);`)

What you did, calling a constructor on an object when not inside another constructor for that object, should probably raise a compiler warning, if not an error, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes sense and helps A LOT!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `SecondForm` is `nil` until you assign it.

Try something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ShowForm2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TSecondForm.Create(nil) do try
     ShowModal;
  finally
     Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 though I have to say that this is about the only scenario in which I can tolerate the use of `with`.

Comment: Yeah, this is the only scenario in which I use `with`.